# Unable to Create COMMIT inside PostgreSQL 11.5 Procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to learn PostgreSQL stored procedures. Specifically creating the procedure below in PSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BUILD_AND_POPULATE(INOUT cresults refcursor) 
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL 
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        BEGIN; -- I've tried removing this but the behaviour is the same
        cresults:= 'cur';
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS procsampledata;
        CREATE TABLE procsampledata as select x,1 as c2,2 as c3, md5(random()::text) from generate_series(1,10) x;  
        COMMIT;
        OPEN cresults FOR SELECT * FROM procsampledata;  
    END;
$$;
```

Then I execute it like so, but receive an error:

```
postgres=# call build_and_populate(null);
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function build_and_populate(refcursor) line 6 at COMMIT
```

I've tried with AUTOCOMMIT set to both on and off.

This is my Postgres version

```
 PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 8.3.0) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The

```
BEGIN;
```

is wrong and will cause an error. You cannot start a transaction inside a procedure, because there is already an active transaction.

You can end a transaction, which implies that a new transaction is started immediately.

Without the `BEGIN;`, your procedure works just fine.

The problem must be with the way you are calling it. As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html) says:

> Transaction control is only possible in `CALL` or `DO` invocations from the top level or nested CALL or DO invocations without any other intervening command. For example, if the call stack is `CALL proc1()` → `CALL proc2()` → `CALL proc3()`, then the second and third procedures can perform transaction control actions. But if the call stack is `CALL proc1()` → `SELECT func2()` → `CALL proc3()`, then the last procedure cannot do transaction control, because of the `SELECT` in between.

There is probably a `SELECT` in your call stack.

Another possibility is that you explicitly started a transaction with `BEGIN` *before* calling the stored procedure.

This does not work either, which is an undocumented implementation restriction that may be fixed in the future. See [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/99b87249-d08c-8082-340e-84273150b59e%402ndquadrant.com#74880e948075c03e3e209a60dd33af06) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for that Laurenz. I think that you might be on to something. I re-removed that BEGIN; statement, and also commented out the select statements in the procedure to see if they were affecting it. They made no difference. I don't think there's a SELECT in my call stack in that I have no call stack as far as I know. I create the procedure, call BEGIN; then CALL. One thing I notice, it ONLY fails if I execute BEGIN; before CALL. Is that the issue? If so, then does that mean it's not possible to return a cursor from a procedure as (in my understanding) they don't survive past their transaction

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. I have extended the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've been going around in circles with this for a while. It's good to finally get my head around it.

Answer (score 3):

After establishing that `BEGIN;` is not allowed in a procedure and that the client-side `CALL` must not occur from an already started transaction, the question boils down to (as you wrote as a comment):

> *"does that mean it's not possible to return a cursor from a
>   procedure as (in my understanding) they don't survive past their
>   transaction"*

It's still possible. There are two kinds of CURSORs: `WITH HOLD` outlive transactions and `WITHOUT HOLD` (the default) don't. You may point a refcursor variable to a `WITH HOLD` cursor in plpgsql with a bit of dynamic SQL. Here's a modified version of your procedure doing that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.build_and_populate(INOUT cresults refcursor)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS procsampledata;
        CREATE TABLE procsampledata as select x,1 as c2,2 as c3, md5(random()::text) from generate_series(1,10) x;
        COMMIT;
        EXECUTE 'DECLARE ' || quote_ident(cresults::text) || ' CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT * FROM procsampledata';                                               
    END;
$procedure$
```

---

```
postgres=# call BUILD_AND_POPULATE('res');
 cresults 
----------
 res
(1 row)

postgres=# fetch all from res;
 x  | c2 | c3 |               md5                
----+----+----+----------------------------------
  1 |  1 |  2 | 11a3d2e637332a25118c2f4d5dac49c0
  2 |  1 |  2 | 4c5b9cb5ec79479a9daa9ae7a131a078
  3 |  1 |  2 | 320b49912e94de90c3370836706c5494
  4 |  1 |  2 | a9ccf45dbbbbec19d18b69cf4a0fc26b
  5 |  1 |  2 | 1a52801f1761cb0e357a4468803473e1
  6 |  1 |  2 | 96c395dad11ee19526bc08b5ad114905
  7 |  1 |  2 | 7d0da9a0cf2520ee871185677d7062cf
  8 |  1 |  2 | 65ecf1e68806a0b9133fa0e47056574e
  9 |  1 |  2 | bae5c688e1ef6b9c389b37ecc7a18342
 10 |  1 |  2 | ed07142f3b51a282c05370890a8af468
(10 rows)

postgres=# close res;
CLOSE CURSOR
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that’s great!